# Setting Track Levels on AVMutableComposition

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I'm trying to combine 4 audio tracks to a single composition, then export this composition to a file. So far my file is created successfully but all of the audio tracks play back at full volume instead of the volume levels I'm trying to set. Here is what I'm doing now:

```
AVMutableComposition *trackComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVAsset *asset1 = ...
AVAsset *asset2 = ...
AVAsset *asset3 = ...
AVAsset *asset4 = ...

NSMutableArray *inputParams = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];

// Add 4 tracks to composition (but only if there are no errors and the track isn't muted
NSError *err;
if(asset1 && ![self trackIsMuted:1]){
    AVAssetTrack *rawTrack = [[asset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [trackComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset1 duration]) ofTrack:rawTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&err];
    AVAudioMixInputParameters *audioParams = [self audioParamsForTrack:compositionAudioTrack volume:[self gainForTrack:1]];
    [inputParams addObject:audioParams];
}
if(asset2 && !err && ![self trackIsMuted:2]){
    AVAssetTrack *rawTrack = [[asset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [trackComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset2 duration]) ofTrack:rawTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&err];
    AVAudioMixInputParameters *audioParams = [self audioParamsForTrack:compositionAudioTrack volume:[self gainForTrack:2]];
    [inputParams addObject:audioParams];
}
if(asset3 && !err && ![self trackIsMuted:3]){
    AVAssetTrack *rawTrack = [[asset3 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [trackComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset3 duration]) ofTrack:rawTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&err];
    AVAudioMixInputParameters *audioParams = [self audioParamsForTrack:compositionAudioTrack volume:[self gainForTrack:3]];
    [inputParams addObject:audioParams];
}
if(asset4 && !err && ![self trackIsMuted:4]){
    AVAssetTrack *rawTrack = [[asset4 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [trackComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset4 duration]) ofTrack:rawTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&err];
    AVAudioMixInputParameters *audioParams = [self audioParamsForTrack:compositionAudioTrack volume:[self gainForTrack:4]];
    [inputParams addObject:audioParams];
}

AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
audioMix.inputParameters = inputParams;

// Export the composition to a file
AVAssetExportSession *export = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:trackComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString guidString]] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4a"]];

[export setOutputURL:outputURL];
[export setOutputFileType:@"com.apple.m4a-audio"];

[export setAudioMix:audioMix];

[export exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{ ... }];
```

The only other interesting thing is the audioParamsForTrack method, which is here:

```
- (AVAudioMixInputParameters *)audioParamsForTrack:(AVAssetTrack *)track volume:(float)vol{
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:vol atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    return [audioInputParams copy];
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? I've tried passing all sorts of different tracks to create the audio parameters but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I saw something about a track's preferred volume - is this something that might help me? I'm a bit stuck at this point, any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: this isn't necessarily an answer to your question but its related, you can set multiple times on a single AVMutableAudioMixInputParameter object. so to set a ramp up and down on the same track you need to set those ramps on the same parameters instance. I didn't understand that at first and thought I needed to add one Parameters object per volume ramp.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but what worked for me was setting the track Id explicitly on the input parameters:

```
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:compositionAudioTrack.trackID];
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Just be sure you are setting the trackId coming from the compositionAudioTrack, NOT the AVAssetTrack object if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging this I can see the issue, but I'm not sure why it's happening.

When you add the params to the array, like this:

```
[inputParams addObject:audioParams];
```

The track id gets set to 0, thus it never attaches to any track:

From the console:

```
<AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters: 0x16eab300, track ID = 0, volume mix: volume 0.010 at time 0.000>
```

I resolved this by not using the audioParamsForTrack method, but doing the work just before the array, like so:

```
NSMutableArray *inputParams = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];

            AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:AudioTrack];
            [audioInputParams setVolume:.01f atTime:kCMTimeZero];

            AVAudioMixInputParameters *audioParams = audioInputParams;
[inputParams addObject:audioParams];

            audioMix.inputParameters = inputParams;
```